# solr dataImportHandler expression with default value

Tags: solr, expression, dataimporthandler

how can i have default value for an expression? i have some thing like

```
<entity name="company" query="select ID, CATEGORY_1, CATEGORY_2 from company">
  <entity name="category"
     query="select id, name from category where id in (${company.CATEGORY_1}, ${company.CATEGORY_2})">
```

know i want to replace ${company.CATEGORY_*} with null if its value is not present.

in current format its query is like `select id from category where id in (308, )` which of course cause error.

i tried `${company.CATEGORY_2?null}` and `${company.CATEGORY_2!=null?company.CATEGORY_2:null}` and  `${company.CATEGORY_2:null}` (some form of expression i known). but none of them works, so what is the correct form of writing this expression?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the string "null" in there, could you modify your SQL to provide it?

e.g.,

```
select ID, COALESCE(CATEGORY_1,'null'), COALESCE(CATEGORY_2,'null') from company
```

Comment: of course i can do that. as the matter of fact i did. just want to know how to do it with solr expressions.